# In the TechEmpower benchmarks, the Netty application does not honor keepalive connections—is this on purpose?

Tags: http, netty

I am in the process of load testing a Netty application I have.  I have been looking to various authorities to try to follow best practices both to learn more about Netty and just to become a better developer.

One of those authorities I'm consulting is the blazingly fast [Netty application that is part of the TechEmpower framework benchmarks](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/frameworks/Java/netty).

I've noticed that this application does not honor the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header that is sent as part of the test.  Specifically, at the end of any given write operation, it closes the connection, even though the [test requests that connections be kept alive](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/search?q=%22Connection%3A+keep-alive%22&unscoped_q=%22Connection%3A+keep-alive%22).  This is of course permitted, but….  Often times seemingly odd choices like this exist for good performance reasons.  Is there a reason that the [Netty application here chooses to close every connection](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/3934542bd2aab91571c5590593fedac4aba275b0/frameworks/Java/netty/src/main/java/hello/HelloServerHandler.java#L101-L114) instead of keeping them alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it only does this when it receive a request to an unexpected path, in which case it just closed the connection after the response was written.

Comment: You are of course correct. Too many hours of code reading. My apologies for the dumb question.